# Abbreviating "of course" to course or 'course - is apostrophe needed to indicate missing word?

Tags: grammaticality, orthography, apostrophe

I'm looking at some dialogue that has been written as "'Course not!". Is the apostrophe here - indicating the missing word "of" - correct, incorrect or optional for clarity? Although it is unlikely that this would be misinterpreted as an instruction not to course.

Comment: Admittedly apostrophes are used in contractions (word splices with obvious deletions) and _o'clock_ uses one to indicate a whole word (as well as the _f_) has been deleted, but the use of one to show omitted words alone would be unusual. I'll dig out my copy of _Truss_; she includes a 'non-standard register, eg piratese' usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of an apostrophe to indicate the omission of complete words from a contraction is rare but not unknown (o'clock). Lynne  Truss, in 'Eats, Shoots and Leaves', includes 'the attempt to represent regionalisms and the like in print [often accompanied by a forest of apostrophes]' [paraphrasing] in her list of acceptable uses for the apostrophe, but does not include this example. I'd say that the unapostrophised version *Course* (when used in sentence or fragment-initial position, and followed by a comma, a 'not', or a variant on 'he/'e is') is, as you indicate, hardly likely to prove ambiguous or lead up a garden path.

Here is an example from ['Echoes of a Trumpet - a legend of Selborne after the Riots; Jean Newland; 1998](http://www.johnowensmith.co.uk/books/ech1873855303.htm):

> James saw this and tried to reassure them, "I'll be alright. It just
> takes a bit o' gettin' used to, that's all. I won't let yer down, I
> promise."
>
> His mother smiled, "We know yer won't, son. Come on, off to yer bed.
> Y' need yer sleep. Meanwhile, I've got to find yer somethin' to wear
> for tomorrer."
>
> "Could I have a little more broth first, please ma?"
>
> "Course yer can, son. 'Ere, I'll get it."

And another from [Glenice, Crossland in 'Christmas Past' {2007}](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wu4IOYPv8qUC&pg=PT72&lpg=PT72&dq=%22+%27Course+yer+can%22+-%22of+course%22&source=bl&ots=FFVUWHvJf9&sig=ACfU3U3FgNLbW-fYhsV92Fl4JjlHuwQxHQ&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22%20%27Course%20yer%20can%22%20-%22of%20course%22&f=false):

> "Can I? Be in your gang? Are you sure?"
>
> "Course yer can. We could do with a good mechanic to look after us bikes."

I'd avoid opting for the apostrophe, but it's really a style choice rather than observance of a well-defined rule. And representations of dialect are not going to be correct as regards standard usages, so worrying too much about this point would be precious. *And in fact, the transcription of 'Brassed off' [here](https://www.quotes.net/mquote/12476) includes an example using the apostrophe (the transcription does not include inverted commas)*:

> Nurse:
> *Is this man bothering you?*
>
> Phil:
> *'Course he is. He's me dad.*

Comment: Thank you, especially for the examples. I'm going to omit the apostrophe for clarity.